# Excel conditional formatting?

Tags: excel-formula

On one sheet I have a vlookup function that places a number under a date going horizontal across the sheet. The input for this function is on another sheet which downloads the date information from a seperate sheet, with these dates that change. On this other sheet each number has a status such as “exchanged” which colours it green. I want to be able for the original sheet with the numbers under the date to pick up the colour/status it is on the other sheet and be that same colour. This colour needs to be able to follow the number as if the date changes from 11/23 to 12/23 the number would move one cell to the right but so far I can’t get the colour to follow.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

As stated my conditional formatting would pick up the colour of the cell on the other sheet but if the date changed and thus the number moved then the colour wouldn’t follow

Comment: We need some sample data and expected output to help you. What have you tried so far? Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It sounds like you just need to copy whatever rules you have for the original sheet's conditional formatting into the cells you want to also be conditionally formatted, and just do a lookup to bring in the value you want validated by the rule for those dates.

Comment: @MarkS. hi I’m relatively new to excel as I have started as an apprentice in the last month or so. I have been able to get it to work by copying the conditional formatting and I don’t know if it’s just because I’m doing it wrong but it only works if I enter it for each individual cell as when I apply it to all of the cells I want it doesn’t work. This doesn’t seem manageable, am doing something wrong or is this something I just need to deal with. Thanks appreciate the reply

Comment: @EvanRadburn then add sample data to articulate and help us visualize what you're trying to accomplish. In the cells with formatting. select conditional formatting and also show us the rules it's validating.

Comment: @MarkS. I have managed to get it to work thanks. Appreciate the reply 